# Getting current image from imageview (android)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` in which I load images from camera and gallery , and I do it using `imgview.setimagebitmap(bitmap)` ,( and I change the image again and again ) it works fine,  but when I try to get the current image back for some processing (applying effect or rotate) it returns me the old image not the current one.

I think the problem is with `imgview.setimagebitmap(bitmap)`. 
can I be helped?

I have the following code:

```
try {
    iv_image.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap source = iv_image.getDrawingCache();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    int a;
    int b;
    a = 11;
    b = 12;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to obtain the batman as follows :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap()
```

Comment: it still gives you the original image?